# How to modify the laravel breeze to send the Reset, Verification, forget password Mail via Jobs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-10, laravel-breeze

How to modify the laravel breeze to send the Verification, forget password Mail via Jobs or Queue as i have observed while user gets registered the page keeps loading till the mail get send...
it seems like they are not queuing the mail or not sending the mail via job
its a sync behaviour how to make it async so that the page not get blocked!
version php 8.2
laravel 10

sync mail to async of laravel breeze (default mail - forget-password mail , verify mail, )

Comment: Check your QUEUE_CONNECTION variable in env file. If it is sync, change it to database.

Comment: Check this [link how to queue laravel user verification email](https://aregsar.com/blog/2020/how-to-queue-laravel-user-verification-email/) it will help you.